# How to resolve NoSuchElement: null in Java Sap Hybris?

Tags: java, spring, iterator, sap-commerce-cloud

I create an action that modified a value into one or more items (Order), order in status "wait for manual export" into "export", now when i selected the Orders and click on action button nothing change and into the log i have this error :

```
ERROR [hybrisHTTP33] [ManualOrderExportAction] 
ERROR: java.util.NoSuchElementException: null
at java.util.Collections$EmptyIterator.next(Collections.java:4210) ~[?:?]
at myExtension.backoffice.actions.ManualOrderExportListAction.perform(ManualOrderExportListAction.java:37) [?:?]
```

Code:

```
@Resource(name = "businessProcessService")
private BusinessProcessService businessProcessService;

@Override
public ActionResult<Object> perform(ActionContext<Object> actionContext){
    HashSet<OrderModel> hashSet = (HashSet<OrderModel>) actionContext.getData();
    try
    {
        businessProcessService.triggerEvent(hashSet.iterator().next().getOrderProcess().iterator().next().getCode() + "_" + "SaitManualExportEvent" ); //line 37 that generate error.
        Messagebox.show(POPUP_MESSAGE);
        return new ActionResult<>(ActionResult.SUCCESS);
    }
        catch (final Exception ex)
    {
        LOG.error("ERROR: ", ex);
        return new ActionResult<>(ActionResult.ERROR);
    }

}
```

Comment: your `hashSet.iterator()` has no elements in it

Comment: Or `hashSet.iterator().next().getOrderProcess().iterator()` has no elements.

Comment: I activate debug and hashSet have the element that I selected into the Backoffice application.

Comment: @kiner_shah how I do resolve?

Comment: then in this case, please do `while(iterator.hasNext()){ iterator.next());` that way you validate first that you have a "nextElement" before calling `.next()`

Comment: Please split line 37 such that you can tell if the first or second `next()` throws the exception.

Comment: @SMA I have the same error also with while(hashSet.iterator().hasNext(){ businessProcessService.triggerEvent(hashSet.iterator().next().getOrderProcess().iterator().next().getCode() + "_" + "SaitManualExportEvent");}

Comment: What is `businessProcessService.triggerEvent` supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below lines:

```
...
businessProcessService.triggerEvent(hashSet.iterator().next().getOrderProcess().iterator().next().getCode() + "_" + "SaitManualExportEvent" ); //line 37 that generate error.
Messagebox.show(POPUP_MESSAGE);
return new ActionResult<>(ActionResult.SUCCESS);
...
```

should be changed to, something like:

```
...
if (hashSet.iterator().hasNext())
{
    // NOTE: Don't know the data type returned by getOrderProcess(), so
    //       assumed a dummy data type OrderProcess 
    OrderProcess o = hashSet.iterator().next().getOrderProcess();
    if (o.iterator().hasNext())
    {
        businessProcessService.triggerEvent(o.iterator().next().getCode() + "_" + "SaitManualExportEvent" );
        Messagebox.show(POPUP_MESSAGE);
        return new ActionResult<>(ActionResult.SUCCESS);
    }
}
...
```